# Docker Containers Running but Still Cant Access the App

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

My docker compose file seems to be running just fine and in the docker dashboard I see the appropriate containers working. When I go to http://localhost:8080/ all I see is an error message which reads: 'This page isn’t working. localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE'. I am not sure how to solve this. I saw somewhere to replace localhost with '0.0.0.0', but am not sure how to do that in this context and I feel like I have seen it work with localhost so I am not sure what to do with the information. I have checked other sources to see what I am doing incorrectly and am not finding a good solution. I would love to ask for any advice on this matter!

docker compose

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  dev:
    image: filamentgraphql/filament-dev
    container_name: 'filament-dev-hot'
    ports: 
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - node_modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm run dev:hot
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'
    volumes:
      - "./data/redis:/usr/src/app/data"
volumes:
  node_modules:
```

docker-dev

```
FROM node:12.16.1
RUN npm install --global webpack
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 4000
```

dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.16.1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 4000
ENTRYPOINT node ./server/server.js
```

server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
const redis = require("redis");
require('dotenv').config();

// Mongo DB Setup
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MONGO_URI = process.env.MONGO_URI;
mongoose
  .connect(MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    dbName: 'Filament',
  })
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to Mongo DB'))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

// Redis Setup
const client = redis.createClient({
  host: 'redis-server',
  port: 6379
})
client
  .on("error", err => console.log("Error " + err))
  .on('connect', () => console.log('Redis client connected'));

// Filament Setup
const filamentMiddlewareWrapper = require('../filament-library/filamentMiddleware')
const filamentMiddleware = filamentMiddlewareWrapper(client)

// Express setup
const app = express()
const PORT = 4000;
const schema = require('./schema');

app.use(express.json())
app.use('/filament', filamentMiddleware)
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP((req) => ({
    schema,
    graphiql: true,
    context: {
      req,
    }
  })),
);

app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log(`GraphQL server is on port: ${PORT}`));
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "webpack",
    "client": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "start": "nodemon server/server.js",
    "json-server": "json-server --watch fake-database.json",
    "dev": "npm run client & npm run start & npm run json-server & redis-server",
    "dev:hot": "npm run client & npm run start"
```

Comment: Is your server inside the container listening on port 4000 and you try to access it on port 8080?
If that is the case you can change the port by setting the env or change the port mapping in the docker-compose to 8080:4000

Comment: You can also use a host Node installation for day-to-day development, and then package it in a Docker image for deployment (using your unqualified `dockerfile`, with no `volumes:`).

Comment: I am using webpack to route 8080 to 4000, will that account for what you are talking about?

Comment: Could you solve your problem? Is there more info to improve the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your open and published ports does not match. You need to fix your `docker-compose.yml`, in `.services.dev.ports.[0]` (change second port to the internally opened port with Node):

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  dev:
    image: filamentgraphql/filament-dev
    container_name: 'filament-dev-hot'
    ports:
      # Fix port here
      - '8080:4000'
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - node_modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm run dev:hot
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'
    volumes:
      - "./data/redis:/usr/src/app/data"
volumes:
  node_modules:
```

Comment: I am using a command in my package.json ```"dev:hot": "npm run client & npm run start"```  the ```npm run client``` starts my webpack which should route all requests to 8080 to port 4000. Will this solve the problem vs mapping '8080:4000' in the docker compose file? I also did try it with '8080:4000' in the docker compose and the error message was 'cannot get /'

Comment: `I also did try it with '8080:4000' in the docker compose and the error message was 'cannot get /'`: This means it's not a problem of ports, but the express server configuration.

Comment: `I am using a command in my package.json "dev:hot": "npm run client & npm run start" the npm run client starts my webpack which should route all requests to 8080 to port 4000. Will this solve the problem vs mapping '8080:4000' in the docker compose file?`

It depends on to which IPs are you redirecting: each container has a local IP in a private LAN. For example, redirecting from one container to another using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` will not work.

Comment: In your container, you define an `entrypoint` in the `Dockerfile` and a `command` in the `docker-compose.yml`. This means the container executes something like this as a init command:
`node ./server/server.js npm run dev:hot`, which I don't think is what you want. Furthermore, it will be much easier, faster and optimized to use Docker to remap ports instead of a separate `node` command/service, unless you really need it for some reason not commented here.